# Proving $f(x)=x^2 +3x+1$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ by definition

Tags: analysis

***Def***: A function is **continuous** if f : I → R at c ∈ I means that for every ε > 0 there exists a δ > 0 such that for all x ∈ I, |x-c| < δ => |f(x) - f(c)| < ε

**Prove** that $f(x)=x^2 +3x+1$ is **continuous** on $(0,1)$ by definition.

I know how to prove that a function is continuous at a given point, but I don't know how to pick delta so that it satisfies the open interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a function is continuous on $(0,1)$ if it is continuous at every $c \in (0,1)$. We have

$$ |f(x) - f(c)| = |x^2 + 3x + 1 - c^2 - 3c - 1| = |x^2 - c^2 + 3(x - c)| \leq \\
 |x-c||x+c| + 3|x - c| \leq 5|x - c|. $$

Thus, given $\varepsilon > 0$, we may choose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{5}$ and then if $|x - c| < \delta$ then

$$ |f(x) - f(c)| \leq 5|x - c| < 5\delta = \varepsilon. $$

Comment: How did you derive this last part? |x−c||x+c|+3|x−c|≤5|x−c| @levap

Comment: Since $x,c \in (0,1)$ we have $|x + c| < 2$ and so $|x - c||x + c| + 3|x-c| < 2|x-c| + 3|x-c| = 5|x-c|$.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint using the triangular inequality and the binomial formula:

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x^2+3x+1-(x_0^2+3x_0+1)|$$
$$=|x^2-x_0^2+3(x+x_0)|\leq |x^2-x_0^2|+3|x-x_0|=|x+x_0||x-x_0|+3|x-x_0|$$